# 7zip - Delete files not matching extension

Tags: command-line, compression, 7-zip, archiving

I have an existing `archive.7z`, which contains some `.txt`,  `.bin` and  `.log` files.
I would like to delete all files with extension different from `.txt` using 7zip command line from Windows cmd.

I try this command but doesn't work:

> 7z -t7z d -r "D:\Data\archive.7z" !*.txt

how to delete all not `.txt` files without extract and compress again the archive?
 Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -x switch.

> -x (Exclude filenames) switch
>   Specifies which filenames or wildcarded names must be excluded from the operation.

Comment: It works. The command I used is: `7z -t7z d -r "D:\Data\archive.7z" -x!^*.txt`